# tfs powershell script to overwrite file while creating branch

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

Is there any Script to overwrite file or (change the context of a file.txt) while creating Branch TFS on visual studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we cannot call any script while creating a Branch on Visual Studio.

You need to overwrite the file manually after complete creating the branch.

**Update:**

Just open the project branch in **Windows Explorer**, then copy and paste all the files to the branch to overwrite the existing files.  Visual Studio will detect the changes automatically, then you can check in the changes to the new created branch.

Comment: So , How can we do it ?

Comment: @MohamedBENAMAR Just navigate to the created branch, open the file which you want to be overwritten and edit directly, change the file based on your requirement, then save it. You can also delete it first, then add the new one by "Add items to folder" option.

Comment: thanks a lot ,
But i have various files ! so it's so embarrassing to do it manually

Comment: @MohamedBENAMAR Just open the project branch in Windows Explorer ,then copy and paste all the files to the branch to overwrite the existing files.  Visual Studio will detect the changes automatically, then you can check in the changes to the new created branch.